# Enabling QUIC / http/3 on multiple domains with NGINX 1.25

Tags: nginx, quic, http3

[NGINX 1.25 introduced support for http/3 (over QUIC).](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_v3_module.html) To enable it, one can add

```
listen 443 quic reuseport;
```

to the `server` block, alongside the likely existing

```
listen 443 ssl http2;
```

However, if I add the `quic` listen for more than one server block (which all have a different `server_name` set), then NGINX rejects the config with the following error:

```
[emerg] 2611#2611: duplicate listen options for 0.0.0.0:443 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site.conf
```

It is possible to listen on *different* ports for different domains, but that doesn’t seem to be user-friendly — Firefox will display the port number in the url, even if it loaded the page over http/2 first and then got the http/3 port from an `Alt-Svc` header. It’s also tedious to manually allocate ports and to configure the firewall for this.

All my `server` blocks are using the same certificate. All domains that I have a `server` block for are subject alternative names in the single certificate. [RFC9114 says that http/3 clients must support Server Name Indication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9114.html#name-connection-establishment), but even without it, because all my domains use the same certificate, it should be possible in theory to establish a connection and then decide what content to serve based on the `Host` header. This is not what happens though, when I send a request over QUIC, NGINX serves from the `server` block that the `listen 443 quic` is in, it seems to ignore the server name.

Is it possible with NGINX 1.25 to serve multiple domains over http/3 all on port 443?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, nginx can serve http/3 on multiple virtual hosts, but `reuseport` option is supported only for 1 virtual host per the same `listen IP:PORT` directive.

So, you should use different IPs for your virtual hosts or remove `reuseport` option.

Answer (score 4):

When you want to use SNI in Nginx, with quic, you set up multiple listen directives, but only single one with reuseport such as:

```
listen 443 quic reuseport;
http2 on;
http3 on;
http3_hq on;
quic_retry on;

server_name _;
location / {
    add_header Alt-Svc 'h3=":$server_port"; ma=86400';
    add_header x-quic 'h3';
    add_header Alt-Svc 'h3-29=":$server_port"';
...
}


listen 443 ssl;
listen 443 quic;
server_name host1.domain.tld;
location / {
    add_header Alt-Svc 'h3=":$server_port"; ma=86400';
    add_header x-quic 'h3';
    add_header Alt-Svc 'h3-29=":$server_port"';
...
}

listen 443 ssl;
listen 443 quic;
server_name host2.domain.tld;
location / {
    add_header Alt-Svc 'h3=":$server_port"; ma=86400';
    add_header x-quic 'h3';
    add_header Alt-Svc 'h3-29=":$server_port"';
...
}
```

Note, only a single (in this case default) entry says "reuseport". All other entries simply say quic.

This allows you to do both HTTP/3.0 (quic) and server name indication (SNI) across multiple hosts with SNI

Comment: Additionally, which listen directive contains “reuseport” doesn’t matter. It just has to be specified once in any listen directive. The order doesn’t matter.

Answer (score 3):

You should specify "reuseport" only once, and nginx will use it for all hosts with the same host-port pair.

No need for different IPs.
[nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen)